# I go to school on foot every day or I go to school every day on foot

Tags: prepositions, word-order, determiners

Could I write:

> I go to school every day on foot

or should "every day" be at the end of the sentence?

How about:

> - go to school by bike
> - go to school by my bike

Are both of them okay?

Comment: You can, but "I walk to school every day" might be even better.

Answer (score 2):

> Could I write: " I go to school every day on foot" or "every day" should be at the end of the sentence. How about: Go to school by bike Go to school by my bike Are both of them ok?

These are correct: Every day I go to school on foot.  I go on foot to school every day.  However, a native speaker would be most likely to say: I walk to school every day.

In my opinion, "by my bike" would be better put: I go to school everyday on my bike. Or: Every day I go to school on my bike. Or: I use my bike to get to school every day.

Comment: Everyday is an adjective.  You should use "every day"  instead of "everyday".

Comment: Or, _I bike to school every day._ Also, I'd use _ride_ instead of _use_ (i.e., _I **ride** my bike to school every day_), but that might be regional.

Comment: @ Khan Thanks, I use voice to type and often do not notice when it autocorrects me. You are correct.

Answer (score 2):

I agree with Willow on the preference for "walk" rather than "go on foot".

Apropos the bike, I'd say "I cycle to school [every day]".  "I bike to school" would also be okay, as would "I ride my bike to school".  Willow's are good, too, though possibly a little more formal.

The word "bike" has become a bit ambiguous, with the increase in numbers of motorbikes.  Most motorcyclists refer to their machine as simply their "bike", without mentioning that it's not a push-bike.  Which is why I choose to use the verb "cycle", which (so far!) hasn't been co-opted by motorbike riders.

Comment: While it is true that the noun "bike" can refer to either a bicycle or a motorcycle (slang), the *verb* "bike" still only refers to the act of riding a bicycle.

Answer (score 0):

> I go to school every day on foot.
>
> I go to school on foot every day.

Both are grammatical, but the use of every day at the end of the sentence is more common.

Besides, the use of the verb "walk" is more usual than the phrase "go on foot"

> I walk to school every day.

As for:

> I go to school by bike.
>
> I go to school by my bike.

Both are grammatical, but the former is far more common.

Comment: "I go to school by my bike."? Hmm... (half a minute later) I found this: http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/288596/why-is-i-go-to-work-by-my-bicycle-wrong. You may want to check it out.

Answer (score 0):

I go to school on foot everyday ( emphasis on " on foot)
Ex:  How to you go to school every day?
I go to school on foot every day.

2. I go to school everyday on foot. ( Emphasis on " everyday)
   Ex: How often do you go to school on foot?
   I  go to school on foot every day.